# Redis Fails to deploy to Windows Azure after running in emulator

Tags: azure, redis, azure-cloud-services

After deploying the redis application in azure , not able to deploy it in cloud.
Error : An existing connection was forcibly closed by remote host.

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your internet connection.Likely to be an issue with the connectivity and speed.

Answer (score 1):

For that you will have to give the cloud private ip address to the redis connection.

```
import redis.clients.jedis.Jedis

Jedis jedis = new Jedis('private ip',6379,'15000')
```